# How to exclude server module from web module in Razzle

Tags: razzle

There is a library that is being used only when the application is running on the server.

```
isBrowser() ? console.log('broser') : require('datadog-node-utils/logging');
```

the module `datadog-node-utils` should be bundle on the server, but not in the static vendor.

In my razzle config, I tried to exclude this library.

```
 if (target === 'web') {
      config.module.rules.push.exclude = [/\datadog-node-utils/, /\winston/];
...
```

But no luck.

The library is always present on the bundle :(